# Answering closed questions

Tags: bug

(Possible) bug: [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/35662/2064) was posted a few minutes ago, despite that the question was closed an hour earlier.

Comment: Looks like more then a possible bug. Good find.

Comment: @Kortuk - It happened before. Russell also posted an answer to a closed question once. It's possible that the edit box for new answers shows more often, I wouldn't know, since I don't go looking for it on closed questions.

Comment: I have a feeling it deals with client side verification of the post being allowed, but I really dont know, I have bumped it up the moderator channels.

Comment: I sometimes just open a lot of questions in tabs that interest me and then read/answer them sometimes hours later. The edit box show upon opening the tab and never disappears unless I refresh the page. Can that be an explanation of what happens?

Comment: @jippie - sounds plausible. But in that case the "submit" should be refused. The site has some pretty advanced functionality, it should be possible to check when submitting. Either way, it needs fixing. (BTW, currently 51 open tabs in Firefox :-))